# Permissible to wipe over leather shoes during Wudu?

Tags: wudu

While doing wudu in my office, it is not convenient to wash my feet with water. With washbasins only,  it is quite difficult to lift your feet upto the basin in office wear, not to mention the wet floor left behind in the end as well, also, takes longer.

I know if you're wearing leather socks, you can wipe over them, as masah... can the same be applied to leather shoes, with cotton socks underneath?. Please note I would do a full ghusl/shower in the morning before putting the socks/shoes on.

JazakAllah.
Rizwan

Comment: It isn't even wiping over socks is discussed as the analogy fails to some extent.

Comment: Do you mean wiping over socks? after removing the Shoes. Then Yes.

Answer (score 1):

One of the conditions before wiping over the shoes or socks becomes valid is that it covers the area of the foot that needs to be washed i.e. until the ankles. This condition is agreed upon as far as I know.

If the shoe covers until the ankles, then it would be allowed to wipe over it. It would take the same ruling as the khuff (leather socks/shoes). There is no difference in this between socks and shoes.

However, if the shoe does not cover the area of washing and the cotton socks cover part of the area, then it takes the same ruling as if your foot was covered with cotton.

If you follow the opinion that you can wipe over thick cotton socks even if they are not leather, then you could wipe over them.

If you follow the major opinion that it is only allowed to wipe over leather, then you cannot wipe over it since it does not fulfill the condition of covering the proper area.

Answer (score 0):

You can wipe over shoes yes - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OgHbIVXRyU the answer on Huda TV by Sh. Assim Al Hakeem and also http://www.madeenah.com/wiping-over-socks-shoes-during-wudhu/